# PDO : get result from SELECT query

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to get result from a prepared SELECT query, but i get this error :

> PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /..../php/my.php on line 50

Here is the code :

```
// Prepared statement
$queryA = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM test WHERE a_id = :id AND created_email = :email");

// Execute statement
$result = $queryA->execute(array(
    'id'        => $id,
    'email'     => $emailAddress
));

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {   // Line 50

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

...
```

Comment: Is your query generating any error?

Comment: `num_rows` is used in mysqli not in PDO

Answer (score 0):

To get the data from a statement, you have [basically three options](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#foreach):

- foreach over `PDOStatement` object
- use familiar while with `PDOStatement::fetch()` method
- get all the rows in the form of array using `PDOStatement::fetchAll()` method

So in your case it could be

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM test WHERE a_id = :id AND created_email = :email");

// Execute statement
$stmt->execute(array(
    'id'        => $id,
    'email'     => $emailAddress
));

foreach ($stmt as $row) {
```

if you want to process the data right in place.